How to connect to my Windows 10 machine through VPS?
I have a Windows 10 machine at work and I also have an EC2 machine, I wanted to know how I can connect to my Windows via my EC2 machine. I need to have shell access from my windows on my EC2.
I've already tried using reverse tunnel but it doesn't work, I think I'm configuring something wrong.

I'm having a little trouble parsing what you're trying to do. I feel like you have a windows machine behind a nat or other restrictive network, and are trying to tunnel out to/from a machine outside in AWS? What're using the shell for and how is it failing?

Can you explain what has been tried for the reverse tunnel and any errors or diagnostic messages which were reported?

I'm trying to do this so I can run scripts, transfer files, and manage Windows 10 from a safe location without having to open ports or expose the local machine to security risks.
I'm not able to create this shell, I tried this way, which is what I found on the internet:
ssh -i path\to\key.pem -R 2222:localhost:22 ubuntu@ec2.host
And on my ec2 it ran:
ssh -p 2222 user@localhost
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 2222
but it doesn't work, I already created an ssh key and put it in authorized_keys on ec2, I can connect to ec2 but I can't access Windows from it

“without having to open ports” - This is a requirement one that won’t be possible if you are behind a CGNAT

Opening a port I managed to attempt a connection from ec2, but now it is asking for a password, as I have not configured a password either in ec2 or in windows:
ssh -p 2222 user@localhost
user@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
user@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
user@localhost's password:
user@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
